# Spring Data JPA causes EntityExistsException with cascading save

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a `Challenge` class, which has a many to one relationship with the `User` class. It is uni-directional, so it looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserTable")
public class User {
   @Id
   private String userId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ChallengeTable")
public class Challenge {
   @Id
   private String challengeId;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
   @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
   private User user;
}
```

I'm using `Spring Data JPA`, and when I use the `save` method from the `CRUDRepository` on a `Challenge` object, I want it to persist the attached user if that user doesn't already exist, and merge the user into the old user if it does already exist.

I'm using a `findOne(String id)` method in the `UserRepository` to get a user using a `userId`, and that's the user I'm setting in the `Challenge`.

It cascades just fine if the user doesn't already exist, but when I try to save it with a pre-existing user I get the exception:

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.mywebsite.model.User#zk9moo78sx685g6o9yphegdx6lpoll9x]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Changing the `CascadeType` to `ALL` doesn't change anything. Trying to remove the `CascadeType` entirely and manually saving the User first doesn't work either. That gives me the error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.mywebsite.model.Challenge.user -> com.mywebsite.model.User
```

That appears to take place when the transaction exits (as I have my service layer class annotated with `@Transactional`).

If I take out the `@Transactional` annotation and manually persist the user it seems to all work fine. (I still want the cascading saves and transactions on the service level though.)

Taking out the `@Transactional` and trying to use cascading saves fails with a `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` exception because it seems like the `User` becomes a detached entity and it tries to persist it anew, but that primary key already exists so it fails.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here, and help me get cascading saves working with transactions in `Spring Data JPA`?

Comment: Can you post your service method?

Comment: Do you have hashcode and equals methods created for the entities?

Comment: I was missing the hashcode and equals on two entities, but fixing that did not fix the issue.

Comment: The service layer is really just doing a couple things, like setting create and update dates. It used findOne(id) to get the old one and ensure the challenge was owned by the right user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using hibernate-specific cascading options, and everything else I could think of, but I couldn't get cascading saves to work as a Hibernate `CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE` is supposed to. I believe it's a hard limitation of JPA with Spring Data.

Instead, I added a layer between the service and the interface repository. It saves the dependent entity (the user) then the challenge.